# How to upload dbfs files and folders to ADLS in databricks?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am planning to stop using dbfs but instead start using ADLS, I am trying to move my files and folders to ADLS and then I will use the ADLS path to access the files in databricks.

How to go ahead with this requirememt?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the container mounted, then you should just be able to use the `dbutils.fs.cp` command

Mount the container using information here -> https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html

```
spark.conf.set(
      "fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net",
      dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope>", key="<storage-account-access-key>"))
```

once mounted you can copy from one location to another.

```
dbutils.fs.cp(local_filename, 'abfss://<container>@<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net/remote_filename')
```

Obviously, this depends on how many files and how much data you have. You can recursivly copy all files in a folder by adding True as a variable at the end of the `cp` as outlined in the manual.

```
dbutils.fs provides utilities for working with FileSystems. Most methods in this package can take either a DBFS path (e.g., "/foo" or "dbfs:/foo"), or another FileSystem URI. For more info about a method, use dbutils.fs.help("methodName"). In notebooks, you can also use the %fs shorthand to access DBFS. The %fs shorthand maps straightforwardly onto dbutils calls. For example, "%fs head --maxBytes=10000 /file/path" translates into "dbutils.fs.head("/file/path", maxBytes = 10000)".

fsutils

cp(from: String, to: String, recurse: boolean = false): boolean -> Copies a file or directory, possibly across FileSystems
head(file: String, maxBytes: int = 65536): String -> Returns up to the first 'maxBytes' bytes of the given file as a String encoded in UTF-8
ls(dir: String): Seq -> Lists the contents of a directory
mkdirs(dir: String): boolean -> Creates the given directory if it does not exist, also creating any necessary parent directories
mv(from: String, to: String, recurse: boolean = false): boolean -> Moves a file or directory, possibly across FileSystems
put(file: String, contents: String, overwrite: boolean = false): boolean -> Writes the given String out to a file, encoded in UTF-8
rm(dir: String, recurse: boolean = false): boolean -> Removes a file or directory

mount

mount(source: String, mountPoint: String, encryptionType: String = "", owner: String = null, extraConfigs: Map = Map.empty[String, String]): boolean -> Mounts the given source directory into DBFS at the given mount point
mounts: Seq -> Displays information about what is mounted within DBFS
refreshMounts: boolean -> Forces all machines in this cluster to refresh their mount cache, ensuring they receive the most recent information
unmount(mountPoint: String): boolean -> Deletes a DBFS mount point
updateMount(source: String, mountPoint: String, encryptionType: String = "", owner: String = null, extraConfigs: Map = Map.empty[String, String]): boolean -> Similar to mount(), but updates an existing mount point instead of creating a new one
```

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils